# An ajax datasource breaks tab navigation between editable fields on an editable, navigatable Kendo UI grid

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here's the Razor template:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SubmitGridViewModel>()
    .Name(gridId)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable =>
    {
        editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell);
        editable.DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false);
    })
    .Navigatable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .AutoSync(true)
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read(o => o.Action(AppRoute.SubmitGridRead.ToMethod(), AppRoute.SubmitGridRead.ToController()))
        .Create(o => o.Action(AppRoute.SubmitGridCreate.ToMethod(), AppRoute.SubmitGridCreate.ToController()))
        .Update(o => o.Action(AppRoute.SubmitGridUpdate.ToMethod(), AppRoute.SubmitGridUpdate.ToController()))
        .Destroy(o => o.Action(AppRoute.SubmitGridDestroy.ToMethod(), AppRoute.SubmitGridDestroy.ToController()))
    )
)
```

When I have the LastName field focused and open for editing and I hit Tab to open the FirstName field for editing, it does just that. But immediately it closes the FirstName field for editing and focuses on the LastName field again. When I comment out `.AutoSync(true)` the problem goes away.

I presume it's happening because the async httprequest is coming back and screwing with the field focus somehow.

How can I fix this problem?

I would create a JSFiddle but it needs to rely on an AJAX datasource to show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation,

> [ If `autoSync` is ] set to  true  the data source would automatically save any changed data items by calling the sync method. By default changes are not automatically saved.

So, when you tab out of the text box, the data source registers that as a change and triggers an async update. When the update succeeds, the model is rebound and the view is refreshed. Are you sure you don't have any HTML attributes on the text box or JavaScript that would cause the cursor to focus there by default (i.e. `autofocus` or `{HTMLElement}.focus()`?